# How to turn a 1d interpolation to a 2d interpolation?

Tags: python, interpolation

I have a function of 3 variables that I interpolated over one of them 'z_lens' and I want to turn it to a 2d interpolation over 'm_lens' and 'z_lens'.

How can I do that?

here is the function and 1d interpolation:

```
def delta_t(m_lens, z_lens, y_impact):
    return m_lens * (1 + z_lens) * (0.5 * y_impact * np.sqrt(y_impact ** 2 + 4) + np.log((np.sqrt(y_impact ** 2 + 4) + y_impact) / (np.sqrt(y_impact ** 2 + 4) - y_impact)))


def y_min(m_lens, z_lens, dt_min):
    y_min = fsolve(lambda y: delta_t(m_lens, z_lens, y) - dt_min * u.s, 0)[0]
    return y_min

mm = np.arange(20,100,1)
xx = np.arange(0,5,0.01)
yy = np.array([y_min(20,z_lens,1e-3) for z_lens in xx])
my_ymin = CubicSpline(xx, yy, bc_type='natural')
```

I tried this:

```
def y_min(m_lens, z_lens, dt_min):
    y_min = fsolve(lambda y: delta_t(m_lens, z_lens, y) - dt_min * u.s, 0)[0]
    return y_min
#print(np.sqrt((1 + 5) / 5 ** 0.5 - 2) - y_min(20, 0,1e-3))
mm = np.arange(20,100,1)
xx = np.arange(0,5,0.01)


 yy2d = np.array([y_min(m_lens,z_lens,1e-3) for z_lens in xx and m_lens in mm])
my_ymin = interp2d(xx, mm, yy2d, method='cubic')
```

and got this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-cce0ec18337d> in <module>
     15 
     16 
---> 17 yy2d = np.array([y_min(m_lens,z_lens,1e-3) for z_lens in xx and m_lens in mm])
     18 my_ymin = interp2d(xx, mm, yy2d, method='cubic')

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

can someone please help me? How would you define 'yy'?

Comment: The list comprehension should not contain the `and` keyword, which tries to do the logical AND operation between its inputs. I think you want a nested for-loop equivalent, which would be something like `[...for z_lens in xx for m_lens in mm]` instead.

Comment: it worked, thank you!